# Why do the default implementations of listener interfaces in Android Studio include a nullable parent?

Tags: android, kotlin

Every time I implement a listener interface's required override method in Android Studio (when I use CTRL+I, not write it manually), the parent is always nullable. For example:

```
class Location : AppCompatActivity(), RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener  {
    override fun onCheckedChanged(group: RadioGroup?, checkedId: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

Why is the `RadioGroup` by default nullable? If `onCheckedChanged` is called - doesn't that mean the `RadioGroup` cannot be null?

Comment: My guess: the interface does not declare `@NotNull`, so the code generator assumes a nullable type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why auto generated implementation expect nullable arguments it is safer to expect nullable type from Java (for Java defined methods) for arguments without `@NonNull` annotation. But for methods with annotated arguments implementations will be generated according annotation.

Let's say we have Java interface:

```
/**
 * Java interface
 */
public interface Callback {
    void invoke(Object undefined, @Nullable Object nullable, @NonNull Object nonNull);
}
```

And it's implementation:

```
/**
 * Kotlin implementation
 */
class CallbackImpl : Callback {
    override fun invoke(undefined: Any?, nullable: Any?, nonNull: Any) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

As you can see, annotations was recognised an we have:

- `undefined` - nullable type, but it is user responsibility to define null safety for arguments without annotations. You can change type to `Any`, if you can guarantee null safety.
- `nullable` - nullable type and you can't change it type to non nullable
- `nonNull` - non nullable type and you can't change it type. Despite the fact that it is safe, you can't change type for implementation, it's responsibility of interface

Read [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) about annotations role in Java interop